# What should I consider before wearing Google Glass to a job interview when I do development for them?

Tags: interviewing

I am not sure if it's okay to wear Google Glass to an interview. It seems like many people are worried about their privacy, but I am a mobile application developer and I wear them pretty much all the time since I got them.

Because I am involved in development for Google Glass, it seems natural to wear these to an interview as well. I am aware there may be concerns with this due to privacy/etc, so my question is:

- What should I consider before wearing Google Glass to a job interview when I do development for them?

Comment: **Comments removed.** Comments should be used to clarify and improve the question. For extended discussion please use [chat] or [meta].

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would not.

I would not worry about privacy issues, but about attention that you will call to yourself.
And that has two sides:

- If you caused a good impression, this will make it even better: People will remember you easily. It's also something different to add to the scale when deciding whether or not to hire you — people who embrace new technologies are the ones that will probably adapt easier to programming new languages and in new ways.
- If you caused a bad impression... you will be just "the guy with the glasses".

But anyway, I would bring it, and show it around along with what I have made with it, and explain how it helps me in my development.

Comment: +1: *Bring* it to demonstrate your apps if asked, but don't *wear* it, unless perhaps the interviewer *asks* for a demo.

Comment: "embrace new technologies" is not the same as "embracing the gadget fad of the month". People who flow with the fad are certainly likely to be willing to go with new languages and new ways but that definately does not mean they will "most easily adapt" or even be able to productively adapt.

Comment: @Dunk please suggest a editing to improve my answer on that. I do agree that not everyone who is quickly to embrace a new tech will adapt faster, but i do believe that they have a bigger chance to adapt faster than others, yes. Thanks for sharing your opinion anyway.

Answer (score 58):

I don't think it's appropriate.

There's the usual concerns about the privacy of the interviewers but that's not what I'd be concerned about.

You should be asking yourself why you would want to. You would turn off your cell phone for an interview, you wouldn't check any mobile devices. Laptops, cell phones, hand held computers and any in ear devices would all be put away unless you were demonstrating something so why would you want to have wearable tech that only you could interact with?

If I was interviewing someone and they decided to wear something that could potentially take their focus from the interview or even allow them to have reference material in front of them without me knowing then I would be slightly insulted and I'd question how serious this interviewee was about the job, perhaps even if they were capable at all. Many people in addition to that would also be unhappy as to this breach of their privacy.

Comment: That's actually a really good point. It may direct the focus of the interview itself. +1

Comment: People are distracted all the time - their minds' wandering.  Google glass or any other augmented reality UI is no different

Comment: @NewAlexandria: Sure, but wearing Google Glass, like holding a phone or an open book in your hand, is a rather blatant distraction.

Comment: I an be wearing glass and not have it be streaming data to me then.  At that moment, I'm just wearing it because it is part of my assumed experience.  How is it any different that being heavily tattooed?

Comment: because there's no good reason to be wearing something whose primary functions are a. to communicate and b. to record - neither are interview appropriate

Comment: *At that moment, I'm just wearing it because it is part of my assumed experience. How is it any different that being heavily tattooed?* Because as an interviewer I can probably tell if you're being distracted by your own tattoos or not, whereas I probably can't tell if you're being distracted by glass or not. I'd suggest that wearing glass during an interview is like wearing a bluetooth handset during an interview and I'd not be impressed with someone who did either while I was interviewing them.

Answer (score 15):

No. Do Not.  Allow me to illustrate with some 'wearable tech' that is more mainstream - bluetooth headsets.  Would you walk into an interview wearing a B/T and then say "excuse me let me just remove this nifty device". No, that would be silly - you'd take it off before you went in.

If your involvement in Glasses dev is appropriate for the job, it should be in your c.v., not on your face.

Comment: +1 I'm trying to think of a single example where "I make [for] X" implies "I should wear or carry X throughout my interview". I'm imagining a chef casually torching a creme brule while explaining where they see themself in 5 years... Even a smartphone app developer would keep the phone in their pocket or bag except to show a specific app.

Answer (score 9):

An interesting question for sure!

I'd say bring them but realize that in the current moment you are in uncharted territory.  There's no standard pattern on this yet, and just like the rules for bringing laptops and SmartPhones to interviews have been changing and adapting, I think you want to figure the mileage is going vary widely by the organizations you're interviewing with.

Any interview is generally about:

- Showing what you are capable of - in which case, a development capability you are working with is very relevant!
- Showing you can connect with those around you and be respectful of the limitations of your work place - in which case, the Google Glass could easily be a hindrance.

I'd figure that it's an area you want to negotiate this way:

- Whenever bringing recording devices to an interview, make sure you are in an environment where that will be OK.  Traditionally high stakes security jobs are not OK with recording devices.  Also individuals may not be thrilled by this violation of privacy.  Do two things if you're unsure (1) - figure out the overall rules of the site you'll be visiting, and leave the equipment in the car if the site doesn't allow recording devices (2) - check in with individuals as you meet with them and ask if they mind.  Offer to leave the google glass sitting on the table between you, turned off, or stowed in your bag if this is a problem.
- Make sure that they are not a point for disengagement - they are a device that has a user interface.  Make sure that you are interfacing first and foremost with your interviewers, not with the device.  Same rules as any smart phone - don't spend time messing with the device, and lock out any distractions that may happen - for example, turn off alerts or other notifications.
- If demoing your work - make sure the demo is prepared well and focuses on your work, not on the tool's overall capabilities.  You're not selling the tool, you're selling yourself.

In the end, you want the impression to be "hey, that was a smart guy who I can work with", not "cool toy, weird guy".

Answer (score 6):

"I would love to wonder if a candidate was recording this interview and might potentially question me or sue me down the road", said no hiring manager ever. Bring them in your pocket and offering to demo things with them during relevant parts of the interview? That's probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

What a great conversation piece. You're a developer at a developer position interview and you work on Google Glass. Yes, I would wear them to the interview. It could be relevant to the job.

**This is very important:** Make sure you let the interviewer know that they are Google Glasses and that you have every intention of turning them off. Maybe put them in a pocket.

Leaving them on and not informing the interviewer would be a mistake. Turn off and put away all electronic devices.

Comment: "wearing them" is not the same as "taking them to display"