# Use Moto 360 to reference Q's for interviewer

Tags: interviewing

I have an interview for an internship at a large bank, I have 4 interviews with different VPs (Software engineering, technical team leader, systems managers). I have questions prepared in Google Keep and I can easily access them on my [Moto 360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moto_360). Would it be acceptable when prompted to ask them questions , tell them "I have some prepared, do you mind?" and use my watch to quickly reference them? I think that it would be smoother than taking out my phone and possibly even be a conversation starter seeing as these will probably be tech aware people.

Comment: Be wary of those conversation starters that steer  the conversation away from your willingness, readiness and ability to do the job. Tools are tools until they are also seen as toys. Talking about toys in the midst of an interview that has a set duration would not be the best use of your time.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What should I consider before wearing Google Glass to a job interview when I do development for them?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17373/what-should-i-consider-before-wearing-google-glass-to-a-job-interview-when-i-do)

Comment: If they're on your watch, how can you make notes of the responses you get? This sounds more like an excuse to show off your toy/novelty than a good application of technology.

Answer (score 6):

Having questions prepared is the important part. Where you store them is somewhat secondary. I'd agree that your device may be a conversation starter.

However, recall [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law). I recommend that you also bring along a hardcopy printout in case your Moto 360 chooses exactly this moment to shut down.

It may be more important to think about how you will take notes. (You did plan on taking notes, right?) No matter what fancy gadget you plan on using, also take along an old style paper notepad and two pens (see above). Then simply stick your sheet with your questions into that notepad.

[Be Prepared.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_Motto) It always makes a good impression.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be acceptable when prompted to ask them questions, tell them
>   "I have some prepared, do you mind?" and use my watch to quickly
>   reference them? I think that it would be smoother than taking out my
>   phone and possibly even be a conversation starter seeing as these will
>   probably be tech aware people.

While it might be acceptable, it could seem rather odd. I'd be shocked if VPs were impressed by your watch - I'd expect them to think you simply aren't capable of remembering a few questions you wanted to ask.

Unless the position you are applying for is Smart-watch-reader, far better would to memorize a few questions, or instead ask whatever comes to mind.

Interviews are far more about what you know, and what you think, than what you can look up online.

Comment: Agree, I would find it a negative if someone had to access an app to know what they wanted to ask.